# Stripe .configure() change button & description text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

Is it possible to change the button text when using https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js ... Here's my code. I'd like to populate the "panelLabel" with my data-price attribute and the "description" with my data-description attribute. Thanks.

```
<button data-price="Pay $5.00" data-desc="My description" id="stripe-button>Pay $5.00</>

document.getElementById('stripe-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        handler.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "xxxxxx",
        image: "{{ asset('assets/public/img/logo.png') }}",
        name: "Create Your Subscription",
        description: "CUSTOM DESCRIPTION GOES HERE",
        panelLabel: "CUSTOM AMOUNT GOES HERE",
        locale: 'auto'
    });
```